# Can I create a funtion in python that will create an instance of a class?

Tags: python, function, class, instance

So I'm having this problem: I have created a class and would like to also create a function that allows to create an instance in order to make it reusable. The code I have doesn't work and I have trouble understanding why. 
See for yourselves:

```
class Avatar(object):

    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money


def create_avatar(name, money):
    avatar = Avatar(name, money)
```

And later be able to call:

```
create_avatar("test", 50)
```

Is it at all possible to do it this way? It seems pretty straight forward and logical but doesn't work...
If I then try to call:

```
avatar.name
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    avatar.name
NameError: name 'avatar' is not defined
```

And is there a way to automatically change the variable 'avatar' to the name entered when calling. Or any other more efficient to avoid repeating the same variable...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried returning the new instance from the function instead of just assigning it to a variable local to the function? (This isn't necessarily a useful technique in Python, though, as you could just call the class constructor directly if you aren't doing any additional work inside the function.)

Comment: A class is already a function that returns instances.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what exactly do you mean? Please include any relevant errors or output

Comment: What I would like to do is to call:
create_avatar("test", 50)
And have it create a new instance.
--> The idea would be for example to have a user enter his own variables and automatically create the new avatar to be re-used further in the program.
Also, is it possible to change the variable 'avatar' to whatever the user has input as name. Or is there a better way to later be able to access this particular avatar?
@wnnmaw

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why this wouldn't work

```
def create_avatar(name, money):
   return Avatar(name, money)
```

Maybe you were going for this?

```
def create_avatar(name, money):
   avatar = Avatar(name, money)
   return avatar
```

You have to actually return something to use it outside the method, otherwise it is just a local variable within the method.

---

Although, if you are going to call this method anyways, it doesn't make sense when you can just do

```
avatar = Avatar("test", 2)
```

instead of

```
avatar = create_avatar("test", 2)
```

Comment: I totally agree with your second point. But what I was hoping to do was to be able to later use the avatar created independently (i.e. make it join groups, call it in other functions, etc.).
Can I change the variable name for each new avatar?

Comment: You mean like `avatar = Avatar("name", 1)`, then `avatar.name = "new_name"`?

Comment: No rather create_avatar("test", 1) then test.name = test. If it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, you can do `test = create_avatar("test", 1)`, then `test.name = "other_test"`. That is the same as `test = Avatar("test", 1)`, though

Comment: Indeed... Not sure I'm heading the right way with this, though... Gotta re-think it... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are looking for. If this answer helped, you can accept it